# Wordpress font appearance in Chrome and FF

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

We're using [Astrum](http://themeforest.net/item/astrum-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/5643402) theme in WordPress for our [website](http://www.iccube.com). For the body font, the Theme uses [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) font. But, in Chrome and Firefox it looks strange.

Chrome: 
[image]

Firefox: [image]

An other weird thing is, when I sign in to WordPress, the font looks nice.

Chrome: [image]

Are you experiencing the same and how did you fix this ?

Comment: at which location you are getting this on your website http://www.iccube.com/ ?

Comment: http://www.iccube.com/blog-iccube/ - author and date

Comment: @István Did you resolve it? I tried with Chrome and it looks fine. If the problem still persists I think it's your OS that's rendering the font in a wrong way.

Comment: I'm testing on different OS's and browsers around the world and will come back to show the results.

Comment: @needaname It's not resolved yet. I have win 7 and it was tried on other machines with win 7. In linux we don't have that issue

Comment: @István Confirmed myself, it renders like that with Firefox too.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/214

Comment: You could try to increase the font size by 1 and see if it helps..

Comment: Wait..do you have ClearType enabled?

Comment: @needaname where can I check that?

Comment: look http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearType/tuner/tune.aspx

Comment: ClearType is enabled. But if that would resolve, we can't ask the users to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it [Astrum](http://themeforest.net/item/astrum-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/5643402) already has Open Sans as a web font, and I can see this line at the beginning of the first `<style>` tag on your blog [iccube.com/blog-iccube/](http://www.iccube.com/blog-iccube/)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,700);
```

Can you try commenting out that @import line and see if that helps?

**EDIT:**

The above suggestion did not work, so recommended commenting out any `@font-face` rules for Open Sans in the theme style.css. (See comments)

Comment: It doesn't help. Changes the font in the whole page.

Comment: Okay, what about your Astrum theme style.css? Make sure it does not have any `@font-face` rules for 'Open Sans' because it's already `@import`ed

Comment: It has `@font-face` rules for 'Open Sans', but it works as before if I comment out this part.

Comment: I just did a reload of your blog in my Chrome browser and the meta information in your blog looks better now. I would avoid the `@font-face` rules for Open Sans in your local theme's style.css anyway, because Google would handle that for you when you do an `@import`

Comment: Now it looks nice. I just deleted the commented out `@font-face`. And looks ok also by adding back the deleted `@font-face`. I used Incognito Window in Chrome to test it after updates, so the cache can't be the problem. It works, but I don't know why...

Comment: Better to keep the `@font-face` rules for Open Sans commented out or deleted, because they were pointing to different woff files ... that should keep your blog meta looking nice.When your blog still had that strange font appearance, I noticed there were 2 woff files for Open Sans light; now there's just one, so that's good!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51684/discussion-between-gerryong-and-istvan)